# Sitecore presentation layout not rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8

I'm currently facing an issue with sitecore where when attaching certain components to presentation on different version doesn't reflects on web, I've tried publishing all the renderings and resetting the item layout but on web it shows differently.

Looking at the log it shows me following info when saving presentation detail in sitecore,

```
3724 10:29:24 INFO  AUDIT (sitecore\Userx): Set layout details: master:/sitecore/content/Home, language: en, version: 1, id: {110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}, layout: <r xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <d id="{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}" l="{024E6CE1-8850-4125-806B-E4852B982BAA}">
    <r ds="" id="{373AA013-BCCB-4609-A843-91179858349E}" par="" ph="htmlHead" uid="{88FC3512-202B-41E9-B7FA-F00B4824CBAD}" />
    <r id="{363CB014-0800-4017-839B-98A7F4D92274}" ph="header" uid="{6AB600BC-233E-47CD-AA5D-01D44D0FC434}" />
    <r ds="{8038D5DD-45AE-4C98-A7E4-CF76196D0B17}" id="{F7F58313-7038-4F98-84BB-A374B3BD26F9}" par="" ph="mainMenu" uid="{EB55705C-63B7-43AF-8AA7-C504E52B7086}" />
    <r ds="" id="{7797C544-2B26-4A9D-90F1-9AE167A442DF}" par="CssClass=%7B4FEEB35D-C873-40C4-85A4-55E292087764%7D&amp;SlideShowCss=%7B07064B42-D42A-4EC4-9598-D375EC209221%7D&amp;SlideShowJs=%7B7633A209-9CEC-4966-9003-E25D47D1A8A4%7D&amp;VideoCss=%7B64DAEB64-EC60-41AA-8813-804764A3BD01%7D&amp;VideoJs=%7BCA4366DC-0CE5-43BE-968F-138F9C9FB6A7%7D&amp;MapCss=%7B1D0C5CE5-3B8E-4734-852F-97FB740CE62C%7D&amp;MapJs=%7BED6766CA-5744-49CA-A4F4-D693C8FE6017%7D&amp;ShowMap&amp;ShowVideo&amp;ShowSlideShow=1&amp;ShowThumbnails&amp;MediaCenterTitle&amp;CssBlock=%7BB1EBDC83-5885-4237-BDEB-43A36FAAC358%7D&amp;JsBlock=%7B0EE4FC8B-BFC6-4054-9C0D-08FE522B40E2%7D" ph="main" uid="{EFDE1372-9130-404D-B0C0-D75FDD252C81}" />
    <r id="{53BFFC1F-6335-44D2-BD57-02FDBDB371A9}" ph="main" uid="{7FF0897D-B867-48F4-9CF6-EA762192A6B6}" />
    <r ds="" id="{EBBA0841-E253-4F57-8EB7-BC56854E771C}" par="ColumnsNumber=cols1&amp;CssClass=%7B4FEEB35D-C873-40C4-85A4-55E292087764%7D&amp;IsExpanded&amp;HideDescription&amp;CssBlock=%7BB9A54C96-3D48-4342-ADE3-204D6F5836AC%7D&amp;JsBlock=%7BD98D6873-E5D2-4CE3-9AFB-97E48673DB2C%7D" ph="main" uid="{C0248517-59EF-4F56-95DB-846AFFAA45B5}" />
    <r id="{1E80E520-D892-4854-9A1F-93E84FBCE9C4}" ph="main" uid="{AE5B344A-CBBC-4652-A500-4C75262C27BC}" />
    <r ds="" id="{7797C544-2B26-4A9D-90F1-9AE167A442DF}" par="CssClass=%7B4FEEB35D-C873-40C4-85A4-55E292087764%7D&amp;SlideShowCss=%7B07064B42-D42A-4EC4-9598-D375EC209221%7D&amp;SlideShowJs=%7B7633A209-9CEC-4966-9003-E25D47D1A8A4%7D&amp;VideoCss=%7B64DAEB64-EC60-41AA-8813-804764A3BD01%7D&amp;VideoJs=%7BCA4366DC-0CE5-43BE-968F-138F9C9FB6A7%7D&amp;MapCss=%7B1D0C5CE5-3B8E-4734-852F-97FB740CE62C%7D&amp;MapJs=%7BED6766CA-5744-49CA-A4F4-D693C8FE6017%7D&amp;ShowMap&amp;ShowVideo=1&amp;ShowSlideShow&amp;ShowThumbnails=1&amp;MediaCenterTitle=Featured%20Videos&amp;CssBlock=%7BB1EBDC83-5885-4237-BDEB-43A36FAAC358%7D&amp;JsBlock=%7B0EE4FC8B-BFC6-4054-9C0D-08FE522B40E2%7D" ph="main" uid="{F4C2B972-B189-4C6F-B9C8-BAAF3DF91BE5}" />
    <r ds="" id="{D3EC12FE-8EC5-4FF4-8C82-93EC96C59CA5}" par="CssClass&amp;DynamicContent=%7B06C5AE84-76E1-485F-9B0D-01B791A11DA7%7D&amp;CssBlock&amp;JsBlock" ph="main" uid="{1E13B3AC-DCA4-47D1-9E02-405EF74EC4E5}" />
    <r id="{50625BB8-1FE3-4F96-853C-60544C6C6263}" ph="main" uid="{EF92F1E3-3C26-492F-BEC8-D8905555C717}" />
    <r id="{D3EC12FE-8EC5-4FF4-8C82-93EC96C59CA5}" ph="main" uid="{0FB14ED6-B9A5-419A-AF11-20EB797E3303}" />
    <r id="{2E4B6E9B-3BDC-4DB8-B1B7-5AB65995DD9A}" ph="main" uid="{5380C36B-CFB1-4749-A84F-E36DB49E5471}" />
    <r id="{20A22794-352D-4ACA-ACFF-7AC1E75C6BDB}" ph="main" uid="{D5B5B660-C6C9-4498-B780-E6262CF90A2A}" />
    <r uid="{C62C7D03-8A59-4511-B735-D78D50586FC1}" id="{68796B05-7DCC-4EF1-A717-901A6D48ECD9}" ph="main" />
    <r ds="{EA1236D8-A5D4-48AA-B89C-F134129897EE}" id="{DC075E50-F70A-4A33-9A4D-8356DA6391BC}" ph="footer" uid="{9C195914-5049-421F-853A-170A4F585EEC}" par="" />
    <r ds="" id="{F477F491-BF83-4EA4-A08E-A2E2BDCEC5E7}" par="CssClass&amp;CssBlock=%7B14C8F4F3-21DC-4D96-8483-CE10B8525B7C%7D&amp;JsBlock=%7B31453300-11D1-450F-9921-8E4301B38899%7D" ph="footer" uid="{EB08AB99-165E-486C-AC3B-FE0BB555A3ED}" />
    <r id="{771FFF82-E458-42F7-B859-635C192747E9}" ph="script" uid="{78624A00-0BA6-404D-A98F-F4FC3EF1D3A7}" />
    <r uid="{99C0C425-6B34-428F-8E3E-801065197C45}" id="{F477F491-BF83-4EA4-A08E-A2E2BDCEC5E7}" ph="footer" />
  </d>
  <d id="{B384A18D-CEE0-4D47-83D2-9F5FBA2D0EE2}" l="{73C4F582-E2C9-4964-B072-B10C13602684}">
    <r id="{4A3B916B-2D62-48BA-B7D0-9BF71FBAFE15}" ph="htmlHead" uid="{6F0EF5AB-B325-46E2-9978-E0BB11D71059}" />
    <r id="{42304FBA-0A04-4D4E-B847-E22202F9CC22}" ph="header" uid="{1AF7B85B-F358-4717-A252-3FF652A860A6}" />
    <r id="{9BEE96C2-D34E-4596-BAC3-52EEE7BC4D00}" ph="main" uid="{3FBCD82B-2D04-4C7A-905A-E62DDE1568FB}" />
    <r id="{AFF4258F-D0C6-47F7-B211-C13B37B3CF2B}" ph="main" uid="{82CFBECA-54DB-4795-8586-5AF50B93445C}" />
    <r ds="{555D6380-D213-4219-9F70-D832E7118534}" id="{4ACD7F8D-BFA1-488F-968F-7853C4F69F11}" par="" ph="main" uid="{2F67B3FD-4FE6-44EE-865F-192107253EA0}" />
    <r id="{DC84D23B-1212-479C-AF93-EDD74FC05081}" ph="main" uid="{E87DEC82-6064-4EBA-B8F3-4642F9D6002C}" />
    <r ds="{85B49EE1-AFF0-4969-9353-8961CA409BFE}" id="{F98C8BC5-1B13-4E42-89A9-ACEBDA9CE64A}" par="" ph="footer" uid="{D418395E-7CB6-4269-88A8-5CB47F538E1E}" />
    <r ds="{4656DAEB-4592-4C62-B16D-BA87443DB79D}" id="{A0C01814-F954-4FC8-8162-478423A5E944}" par="" ph="footer-extras" uid="{568D3FF1-5058-474A-89B4-BF1DC72A42B9}" />
    <r id="{DE4DA7DC-FCC2-4D2B-A7C2-674BFDBA304F}" ph="footer-extras" uid="{0E8E1949-2125-4FAE-8524-88BCA21D2868}" />
    <r id="{9481BA2F-AD4F-4590-A348-DD5426640FCB}" ph="footer-extras" uid="{408A903B-9F53-459B-8F70-C7699FA018FF}" />
  </d>
</r><r xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <d id="{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}" l="{024E6CE1-8850-4125-806B-E4852B982BAA}">
    <r ds="" id="{373AA013-BCCB-4609-A843-91179858349E}" par="" ph="htmlHead" uid="{88FC3512-202B-41E9-B7FA-F00B4824CBAD}" />
    <r id="{363CB014-0800-4017-839B-98A7F4D92274}" ph="header" uid="{6AB600BC-233E-47CD-AA5D-01D44D0FC434}" />
    <r ds="{8038D5DD-45AE-4C98-A7E4-CF76196D0B17}" id="{F7F58313-7038-4F98-84BB-A374B3BD26F9}" par="" ph="mainMenu" uid="{EB55705C-63B7-43AF-8AA7-C504E52B7086}" />
    <r ds="" id="{7797C544-2B26-4A9D-90F1-9AE167A442DF}" par="CssClass=%7B4FEEB35D-C873-40C4-85A4-55E292087764%7D&amp;SlideShowCss=%7B07064B42-D42A-4EC4-9598-D375EC209221%7D&amp;SlideShowJs=%7B7633A209-9CEC-4966-9003-E25D47D1A8A4%7D&amp;VideoCss=%7B64DAEB64-EC60-41AA-8813-804764A3BD01%7D&amp;VideoJs=%7BCA4366DC-0CE5-43BE-968F-138F9C9FB6A7%7D&amp;MapCss=%7B1D0C5CE5-3B8E-4734-852F-97FB740CE62C%7D&amp;MapJs=%7BED6766CA-5744-49CA-A4F4-D693C8FE6017%7D&amp;ShowMap&amp;ShowVideo&amp;ShowSlideShow=1&amp;ShowThumbnails&amp;MediaCenterTitle&amp;CssBlock=%7BB1EBDC83-5885-4237-BDEB-43A36FAAC358%7D&amp;JsBlock=%7B0EE4FC8B-BFC6-4054-9C0D-08FE522B40E2%7D" ph="main" uid="{EFDE1372-9130-404D-B0C0-D75FDD252C81}" />
    <r id="{53BFFC1F-6335-44D2-BD57-02FDBDB371A9}" ph="main" uid="{7FF0897D-B867-48F4-9CF6-EA762192A6B6}" />
    <r ds="" id="{EBBA0841-E253-4F57-8EB7-BC56854E771C}" par="ColumnsNumber=cols1&amp;CssClass=%7B4FEEB35D-C873-40C4-85A4-55E292087764%7D&amp;IsExpanded&amp;HideDescription&amp;CssBlock=%7BB9A54C96-3D48-4342-ADE3-204D6F5836AC%7D&amp;JsBlock=%7BD98D6873-E5D2-4CE3-9AFB-97E48673DB2C%7D" ph="main" uid="{C0248517-59EF-4F56-95DB-846AFFAA45B5}" />
    <r id="{1E80E520-D892-4854-9A1F-93E84FBCE9C4}" ph="main" uid="{AE5B344A-CBBC-4652-A500-4C75262C27BC}" />
    <r ds="" id="{7797C544-2B26-4A9D-90F1-9AE167A442DF}" par="CssClass=%7B4FEEB35D-C873-40C4-85A4-55E292087764%7D&amp;SlideShowCss=%7B07064B42-D42A-4EC4-9598-D375EC209221%7D&amp;SlideShowJs=%7B7633A209-9CEC-4966-9003-E25D47D1A8A4%7D&amp;VideoCss=%7B64DAEB64-EC60-41AA-8813-804764A3BD01%7D&amp;VideoJs=%7BCA4366DC-0CE5-43BE-968F-138F9C9FB6A7%7D&amp;MapCss=%7B1D0C5CE5-3B8E-4734-852F-97FB740CE62C%7D&amp;MapJs=%7BED6766CA-5744-49CA-A4F4-D693C8FE6017%7D&amp;ShowMap&amp;ShowVideo=1&amp;ShowSlideShow&amp;ShowThumbnails&amp;MediaCenterTitle=Featured%20Videos&amp;CssBlock=%7BB1EBDC83-5885-4237-BDEB-43A36FAAC358%7D&amp;JsBlock=%7B0EE4FC8B-BFC6-4054-9C0D-08FE522B40E2%7D" ph="main" uid="{F4C2B972-B189-4C6F-B9C8-BAAF3DF91BE5}" />
    <r ds="" id="{D3EC12FE-8EC5-4FF4-8C82-93EC96C59CA5}" par="CssClass&amp;DynamicContent=%7B06C5AE84-76E1-485F-9B0D-01B791A11DA7%7D&amp;CssBlock&amp;JsBlock" ph="main" uid="{1E13B3AC-DCA4-47D1-9E02-405EF74EC4E5}" />
    <r id="{50625BB8-1FE3-4F96-853C-60544C6C6263}" ph="main" uid="{EF92F1E3-3C26-492F-BEC8-D8905555C717}" />
    <r id="{D3EC12FE-8EC5-4FF4-8C82-93EC96C59CA5}" ph="main" uid="{0FB14ED6-B9A5-419A-AF11-20EB797E3303}" />
    <r id="{2E4B6E9B-3BDC-4DB8-B1B7-5AB65995DD9A}" ph="main" uid="{5380C36B-CFB1-4749-A84F-E36DB49E5471}" />
    <r id="{20A22794-352D-4ACA-ACFF-7AC1E75C6BDB}" ph="main" uid="{D5B5B660-C6C9-4498-B780-E6262CF90A2A}" />
    <r uid="{C62C7D03-8A59-4511-B735-D78D50586FC1}" id="{68796B05-7DCC-4EF1-A717-901A6D48ECD9}" ph="main" />
    <r ds="{EA1236D8-A5D4-48AA-B89C-F134129897EE}" id="{DC075E50-F70A-4A33-9A4D-8356DA6391BC}" ph="footer" uid="{9C195914-5049-421F-853A-170A4F585EEC}" par="" />
    <r ds="" id="{F477F491-BF83-4EA4-A08E-A2E2BDCEC5E7}" par="CssClass&amp;CssBlock=%7B14C8F4F3-21DC-4D96-8483-CE10B8525B7C%7D&amp;JsBlock=%7B31453300-11D1-450F-9921-8E4301B38899%7D" ph="footer" uid="{EB08AB99-165E-486C-AC3B-FE0BB555A3ED}" />
    <r id="{771FFF82-E458-42F7-B859-635C192747E9}" ph="script" uid="{78624A00-0BA6-404D-A98F-F4FC3EF1D3A7}" />
    <r uid="{99C0C425-6B34-428F-8E3E-801065197C45}" id="{F477F491-BF83-4EA4-A08E-A2E2BDCEC5E7}" ph="footer" />
  </d>
  <d id="{B384A18D-CEE0-4D47-83D2-9F5FBA2D0EE2}" l="{73C4F582-E2C9-4964-B072-B10C13602684}">
    <r id="{4A3B916B-2D62-48BA-B7D0-9BF71FBAFE15}" ph="htmlHead" uid="{6F0EF5AB-B325-46E2-9978-E0BB11D71059}" />
    <r id="{42304FBA-0A04-4D4E-B847-E22202F9CC22}" ph="header" uid="{1AF7B85B-F358-4717-A252-3FF652A860A6}" />
    <r id="{9BEE96C2-D34E-4596-BAC3-52EEE7BC4D00}" ph="main" uid="{3FBCD82B-2D04-4C7A-905A-E62DDE1568FB}" />
    <r id="{AFF4258F-D0C6-47F7-B211-C13B37B3CF2B}" ph="main" uid="{82CFBECA-54DB-4795-8586-5AF50B93445C}" />
    <r ds="{555D6380-D213-4219-9F70-D832E7118534}" id="{4ACD7F8D-BFA1-488F-968F-7853C4F69F11}" par="" ph="main" uid="{2F67B3FD-4FE6-44EE-865F-192107253EA0}" />
    <r id="{DC84D23B-1212-479C-AF93-EDD74FC05081}" ph="main" uid="{E87DEC82-6064-4EBA-B8F3-4642F9D6002C}" />
    <r ds="{85B49EE1-AFF0-4969-9353-8961CA409BFE}" id="{F98C8BC5-1B13-4E42-89A9-ACEBDA9CE64A}" par="" ph="footer" uid="{D418395E-7CB6-4269-88A8-5CB47F538E1E}" />
    <r ds="{4656DAEB-4592-4C62-B16D-BA87443DB79D}" id="{A0C01814-F954-4FC8-8162-478423A5E944}" par="" ph="footer-extras" uid="{568D3FF1-5058-474A-89B4-BF1DC72A42B9}" />
    <r id="{DE4DA7DC-FCC2-4D2B-A7C2-674BFDBA304F}" ph="footer-extras" uid="{0E8E1949-2125-4FAE-8524-88BCA21D2868}" />
    <r id="{9481BA2F-AD4F-4590-A348-DD5426640FCB}" ph="footer-extras" uid="{408A903B-9F53-459B-8F70-C7699FA018FF}" />
  </d>
</r>
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch to web database and see all rendering and related items published successfully. I f all published make sure all place holders are correct. and check error log for any exceptions.